# Calling functions saved in a map

Tags: scala, collections, dictionary

I was reading [Scala School](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/collections.html#Maps). According to the guide, Map can contain functions like

```
def adder(x: Int, y:Int): Int = x + y
def add2(x:Int):Int = adder(2, x:Int)
val add3 = adder(3, _:Int)

val map = Map(
  "adder" -> { adder(_, _) },
  "add2" -> { add2(_) },
  "add3" -> { add3(_) }
)
```

OK. Above code is compiled. But How can I call the functions saved in the map? These code doesn't work

```
map.get("adder")(2, 3) // compile error
val adderFunc: (Int, Int) => Int = map.get("adder") // compile error
```

Scala compiler gives this error message

```
[error] /home/user/scalaExample/src/test/scala/CollectionBasicsTest.scala:61: Option[Object] does not take parameters
[error]     map.get("adder")(2, 3) // compile error
[error]                     ^
[error] /home/user/scalaExample/src/test/scala/CollectionBasicsTest.scala:62: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Option[Object]
[error]  required: (Int, Int) => Int
[error]  val adderFunc: (Int, Int) => Int = map.get("adder") // compile error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
map("adder")(2, 3)
```

(`.get` returns `Option` instead of value inside the `map`)

**UPDATE**

As @EndeNeu pointed out, scala's type inference infers the type of the map as `Map[String, ScalaObject]` because you're trying to put functions of different arity into the map.

So, to make above example to work you'll have to put functions that can be generalized to `(Int, Int) => Int` into your map.

I.e. having the functions from you example:

```
def adder(x: Int, y:Int): Int = x + y
def add2(x:Int):Int = adder(2, x:Int)
val add3 = adder(3, _:Int)
```

... you can have this:

```
val map = Map(
  "adder" -> { adder(_, _) },
  "another adder" -> { adder(_, _) }
)

map("adder")(2, 3)
```

... or this:

```
val map = Map(
  "add2" -> { add2(_) },
  "add3" -> { add3(_) }
)

map("add2")(2)
```

... but if you want to store all your adders in the same map you'll have to either generalize them to the common type, that can be called as you expect (with one or 2 arguments?) or cast them using reflection in runtime (but this is not type safe and does not seem to be adequate solution for this case) like this:

```
val map = Map(
  "adder" -> { adder(_, _) },
  "add2" -> { add2(_) },
  "add3" -> { add3(_) }
)

map("adder").asInstanceOf[(Int, Int) => Int](2, 3)
```

Comment: The lambda inside the map will be object and you can't call it as a method then.

Comment: Uhm. Doesn't work.

     assert(map("adder")(2, 3) == 5)

[error] /home/user/scalaExample/src/test/scala/CollectionBasicsTest.scala:61: Object does not take parameters
[error]     assert(map("adder")(2, 3) == 5)
[error]                        ^
[error] one error found

Comment: It doesn't make any difference, the type of that map is `[String, Object]`, the compiler doesn't know that the object takes two type parameters, try it in your REPL, also calling `map("key")` is a bad idea because it's unsafe.

Comment: Then, once saved lambda can't be called as a function forever. right?

Comment: On the other hand if you put into map only functions, and then call `get("adder").flatMap(adder => adder(1)(2))` it will work.

Answer (score 5):

There are two problems here. One is that `get` returns an `Option`. You could use `map("adder")` instead to get the function back.

The second and most basic problem is that you put two completely different things in the map: a function with two parameters and a couple of functions with one parameter. These types are completely different, which means the type inferred for the value of the map is `AnyRef`. So, once you get back such object, you cannot do anything with it, before getting it back to some useful type.

Keep only functions with the same number of parameters in the map, and use the first tip, and things will work.

Comment: After putting functions which have same parameters into a map, I can call them. Thanks. 


    val map2 = Map(
      "adder" -> { adder(_, _) }
    )

    assert(map2("adder")(2, 3) == 5)